# SQLite, copy platform specific dlls to bin folder

Tags: .net, sqlite, dll, platform, post-build-event

I need to get the respective SQLite x86/x64 dlls into the bin folder according to if I build to x86, x64 or Any CPU. Where/how would I specify this in an easy manner?  Assume I have the dlls in /x86/  and /x64/ folders.

I try this in the proj file, but has no effect. The command works when put in build events through Properties tab (without condition), but not when I edit the xml file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent Condition ="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
       copy "$(ProjectDir)x86\*.*" "$(TargetDir)"
    </PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

edit:

So this is how to put conditions in the Build Events 'window':

```
If $(PlatformName) == x86 copy "$(ProjectDir)Libs\x86\System.Data.SQLite.dll" "$(TargetDir)System.Data.SQLite.dll"
```

Still not sure why it doesn't work from the proj file though.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your own bat|cmd file, you may pass arguments required for performing some actions to it and then it will work with the postbuild event string like:

`call "mybatfile.bat" "arguments"`